# Buck Boost Charge Capacitor Balance

Tags: dc-dc-converter, buck-boost

For a buck boost capacitor charge balance, I am curious if adding equation 11.7 and 11.10 is correct? Or is this the average inductor current?

[image: Image is from Fundamentals of Power Electronics Second edition chapter 11]

Comment: Mr. Blue - Hi, Currently your question breaks the [site rule on referencing](/help/referencing) material copied/adapted from elsewhere. To comply with that rule, please [edit] the question and, since this is a printed book which is being copied, add a normal citation as stated in that rule i.e. book title, author(s), page number - it helps to add the publisher & edition too . Also please remember it's your responsibility to follow that rule in future too. TY (Please see the [tour] & [help] as site rules here differ from typical forums.)